# How to acquire lock in git to prevent others from committing?

Tags: git, hook

I need to acquire lock in git to prevent others from committing my file. This needs to be done while doing `git commit <filename>` . I am planing to write a pre-commit hook. Please help how can i achieve this. Don't know git internally does this or not But I need to add this explicitly and intimate the user that somebody acquired the lock.

Answer (score 3):

Git does not support file locking. Because Git is a distributed version control system, this is simply not possible and it also doesn’t make any sense for DCVS. The repository exists locally, and there is nothing that requires users to interact with any remote *by design*.

If Git had locking, it would only apply locks on your own machine, which would be rather useless. And if there was an actual way to lock files on a remote then there are a number of issues that prevent this fundamentally from working: What if I have multiple remotes? What if I add the remote to the repository *after* editing and committing? What if I don’t have a connection to the remote?

Anyway, if there was locking, it would defeat the point of DVCS. Instead, you should learn and get used to how Git works.